# Using subprocess module in python to store the result of "pwd" command

Tags: python, subprocess

I am creating one program. In that program I want to have few commands to run automatically using subprocess module.

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run("pwd")
```

I want to store the location where is the user is now. Like if the user in `/home/user/Documents` then I want to store that location to result variable.

I tried to use `result.stdout` and `result.stderr` but both printed `None`. Even I tried to print result but that do not worked. Is there any way to get the location where is the user is right now. Please reply I need your help.

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_output()`.

Comment: You don't need a subprocess for this. `os.getcwd()` will return the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the subprocess module you can use: `subprocess.check_output()` to check output too but there is another alternative too you can use `os.getcwd()` where the user is in now. Hope it will help.